# Dual display setup with Debian 9 text interface

Tags: debian, text, text-user-interface

I have a NCR EPoS terminal that has a dvi interface for the main screen and a vga for the secondary screen.

Is it possible to have one application running in full screen on the dvi display and one on the vga display and have the two apps tall to each other.

I am trying not to use any desktop environment as I want to have all the ram for the OS and my software

Is what I want to do acually possible with the text interface of Debian or can this only be done in the graphical desktop

Also with Debian 9 where do I put a my command to start my till software.

Normally I would use ./NPoS/NPoS to start the software

Comment: "Full screen" assumes a windowed interface, so it's confusing that you want to do without it. Also, what do you mean by "talk (probably not tall) to each other"?

Comment: This is going to be a tough question to answer without the use of some kind of display manager.

Comment: I have no display manager unless the frame buffer is a display manager. I have a text only version of Debian installed